# Creating a sample timer and am greeted by a TypeError

Tags: python

I've been working on a project for around five minutes, and I just got an error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Can anyone help me see my error?

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier as tst
import time
#timer with notifications

toaster = tst()
#the below input shows how long the timer will last
span_seconds = input('How many seconds will your timer span through? ')
#loops the time until the seconds are up
i = 0
while i < span_seconds():
    time.sleep(1)
    span_seconds-1
    #determines whether the timer is done
if i == span_seconds:
    toaster.show_toast('Timer is up!')
```

Comment: "I just got a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Can anyone help me see my error?" Well, what do you think `TypeError` means? What do you think a `'str' object` is? If the error message says that something `is not callable`, what does that tell you about what's wrong with the code? Now, look at the line of code that it's complaining about. Do you see something that is a `'str' object`? Do you see something that would make `is not callable` a problem? Finally: what do you want that line of code to do? Should it be calling something?

Comment: BTW: that is not the only problem in your code, just the one that actually causes an exception to be raised. Think more clearly about the line `span_seconds-1`: what are you expecting that to accomplish? Will it accomplish that?

Comment: Well, that would mean that the string object is not callable in a while loop. But, I experimented with other data types, such as a list, but they are not callable either. As for your second comment, I want the span_seconds to decrease by one for each iteration over the while loop, so that the seconds will eventually be equivalent to zero.

Comment: What do you think `callable` means? What are you trying to do in the line `while i < span_seconds():`? Do you think that something being `callable` is logically relevant to that task?

Comment: "I want the span_seconds to decrease by one for each iteration over the while loop". Okay. Does `span_seconds-1` cause `span_seconds` to change? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span_seconds` is a string, as returned from [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). You cannot call a `string`. Nor can you call an `int`. You don't *want* to be calling it anyway. You want simply to reference the variable. You can omit the `()` to do that.

Also, your line `span_seconds - 1` doesn't do anything. I'm guessing you're going for something along the lines of `span_seconds = span_seconds - 1` (also written as `span_seconds -= 1`). That line wouldn't accomplish what you're aiming to do, even if written properly, because `span_seconds` is a `string`, not an `int`.

If you change

```
while i < span_seconds():
    span_seconds-1
```

to

```
while i < span_seconds:
    span_seconds -= 1
```

as I mention above, and also change

```
span_seconds = input('How many seconds will your timer span through? ')
```

to

```
span_seconds = int(input('How many seconds will your timer span through? '))
```

converting `span_seconds` into an `int`, your code might behave in the way you want it to.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: But, integers are still not callable within while loops.

Comment: Integers are indeed not callable. "within while loops" is not relevant - things either are, or are not callable. The question is, *why do you think you want to call it*? Because you do not want to "call" `span_seconds`. (What do you think it actually means to "call" something?)

Comment: Thanks! The program is now up and running perfectly.